# How to read a matrix from standard input in python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to read a matrix or a 2D array from standard input.

For example:

```
my_array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How can I read this matrix in standard input using the stdarray or stdio modules?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = input("Enter Array:")
Enter Array:[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> x[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x[1][1]
5
```